# Multiple instances of the Android Facebook SDK on one App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing a library for Android that requires its own Facebook Login. However I forsee issues if the App that is including my library is already using the Facebook SDK, since the Facebook SDK expects to have only a single app_id active at a given moment what complications would happen if I do this (aside from having to define the key hashes of all the apps that use my library)

My question is, is it possible to namespace the Facebook SDK embeded in my library so that it won't conflict if the main app using my library is already using its own Facebook SDK?

Currently the best solution I can find is to just use a webview and do Facebook login using our website.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be possible.